# Haze about 'setState' in React official doc

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am reading react.js official docs.
Here is [one](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) of them.

I am confused about this paragraph:

> setState() will always lead to a re-render unless
>   shouldComponentUpdate() returns false. If mutable objects are being
>   used and conditional rendering logic cannot be implemented in
>   shouldComponentUpdate(), calling setState() only when the new state
>   differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

Question: Why calling `setState()` will avoid unnecessary re-renders if mutable objects are being used and conditional rendering logic cannot be implemented in `shouldComponentUpdate()`?

Answer (score 2):

> [shouldComponentUpdate](https://github.com/kylpo/react-playbook/blob/master/deep-dives/shouldComponentUpdate.md) deep-dive might help you

- Calling setState() will always trigger a re-render of the component(unless you have defined shouldComponentUpdate()). But keeping performance and efficiency in mind, we want the component to re-render only if the state value has actually changed.
- This is where shouldComponentUpdate() lifecycle method comes into play.
  In this method, a check can be done to determine whether the state value has changed. If state has changed, returns true and the component re-renders.
- Mutable objects refer to Arrays, objects etc in javascript. Numbers and Strings are immutable.

**Mutable object example:**

```
const a = [1,2]; // memory address of a is 0xff456e
a.push(3); // memory address of a is 0xff456e(same)
```

**Immutable object example:**

```
 let b = 'Hello'; // memory address of b is 0xee789e
 b = 'World'; // memory address of b is 0xee789f(different because its a new object created with value 'World')
```

- If your component is a PureComponent, then react by default will define the shouldComponentUpdate() to reduce unnecessary re-renders. But you need to use immutable objects for that to work correctly(i.e create a new array or object manually and assign to your state, else your component won't re-render correctly).
- So, the point they are making is this : **Don't call setState() unless the state value has actually changed** if your using a *normal* react component *without* a shouldComponentUpdate() check to avoid situations like this:

> ```
>  this.setState({ items: [1, 2, 3] }); // re-render once
>  // lot of code goes here
>  this.setState({ items: [1, 2, 3] }); // re-render twice
> ```
>
> Note: Although the value of items is unchanged, there is a wasteful re-render of the component caused as shown above. So, avoid setting state if there is no change of value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you read that wrong.

It's a two term conditional:

IF

> mutable objects are being used

AND

> conditional rendering logic cannot be implemented in shouldComponentUpdate()

THEN

[you should call] setState() only when the new state differs from the previous state [so it] will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

(Alteration by me are in brackets.)

Basically, it means that it's up to you to test if you should call `setState` if you can't rely on React's internal tests due to technical limitations on your side.

Comment: Thank you for prompt answer! If my understanding is correct, `mutable objects` means state literal objects. Generally, we can rely on `shouldComponentUpdate()` to let react judge if the component need re-rendering. If we can not rely on it, we should do some check stuff by ourselves. Am I correct? Do you have some examples about situations where we can not depend on `shouldComponentUpdate()` ?

Answer (score 0):

The doc wanted to say that in the following conditions, the re-render will not happen:

1. If shouldComponentUpdate hook returns false.
2. If mutable objects are being used.
3. If some conditional logic is not used for re-render like force update inside shouldComponentUpdate hook.
4. If the effect of calling setState method only change the previous state value.

BTW, I'm still not satisfied that I couldn't make clear enough. :(: