# ReactJS is no Rendering Component

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, axios

I took this all from this example. [Creating a React Login Page](https://medium.com/technoetics/create-basic-login-forms-using-create-react-app-module-in-reactjs-511b9790dede)

So I cannot take any credit. However, this page works fine. I am trying to retro fit it to pushing a React Video Player page.

My code is as follows (Snippet from Axios Post):

```
 if (response.status == 200) {
                console.log("Login successfull");

                var videoPlayer = [];
                this.setState( {isLoggedIn : true });
                videoPlayer.push(<Videoplayer appContext={self.props.appContext} parentContext={this} />);
                self.props.appContext.setState({loginPage: [], videoPlayer: videoPlayer});
```

The existing code was this:

```
var uploadScreen=[];
                uploadScreen.push(<UploadScreen appContext={self.props.appContext}/>);
                self.props.appContext.setState({loginPage: [], uploadScreen: uploadScreen})
render() {
  var browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

  if(this.state.isAuthenticated) {
    return <Redirect to={'/VideoPlayer '}/>
  }
  return(
      //<Router history={ browserHistory }>
      //<Route path="/VideoPlayer" component={() => <VideoPlayer title="Arlo Video" style="home-header"/> }/>
      <div>
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <div>
                    <AppBar
                        title="Login"
                    />
                    <TextField
                        hintText="Enter your Username"
                        id = "username"
                        floatingLabelText="Username"
                        onChange={(event, newValue) => this.setState({username: newValue})}
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <TextField
                        type="password"
                        id = "password"
                        hintText="Enter your Password"
                        floatingLabelText="Password"
                        onChange={(event, newValue) => this.setState({password: newValue})}
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <RaisedButton label="Submit" primary={true} style={style}
                                  onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}/>
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </div>
     // </Router>
  )
}
```

}

My code does not render the VideoPlayer Page and that code is from the standard example at this github

[ReactJS Video Player](https://video-react.js.org/components/player/)

I have a feeling that it has to do with Context but I don't know enough about React or how to debug this using the Chrome tools. My backend is Django. I'm almost thinking of going back to using Jquery so I can get pages at least functioning but wanted to try and learn React.

Any help would be great. The code above is just testing code so I could get some thing functional.

Comment: Can you please share the code of render function?

Comment: Just edited it.

Comment: Do you have a router with route set to display <Videoplayer> when the url is /videoplayer? And what happens when the authentication is succeessful? Does the url change to /videoplayer?

Comment: I took off router for now. It appears this is related to setState. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718709/reactjs-does-render-get-called-any-time-setstate-is-called

Answer (score 0):

Updating the state by returning `null`, empty array `[]` or any initial value will not re-render the component. You need to change the state value to something else and then only the component will be re-rendered.

You may also [take care](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50172248/2138752) of [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) will not re-render the component when shouldComponentUpdate hook returns false.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are seeing that. The code makes the login page array null and then sets the videoPlayer [] to videoPlayer. Can you tell me where you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

The offending code was the following:

```
 AppContext={self.props.appContext}
```

Which was a typo to this:

```
videoPlayer.push(<Videoplayer appContext={self.props.appContext} parentContext={this} />)
```